"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"cart\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"User\""
I'm working on a ecommerce project and getting this when I'm making controller for update cart for user
Here is my code
user model
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Erase if already required
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const crypto = require('crypto')
// Declare the Schema of the Mongo model
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    mobile: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user',
    },
    cart: [
        {
            product: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
            quantity: { type: Number },
            color: { type: String }
        }
    ],
    address: {
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    },
    wishlist: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }],
    isBlocked: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    refreshToken: {
        type: String,
    },
    passwordChangedAt: Date,
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


//Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);


product model
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Erase if already required

// Declare the Schema of the Mongo model
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    slug: { // máy tính dell --> may-tinh-dell
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    brand: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    sold: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    images: {
        type: Array
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Black', 'Brown', 'Red']
    },
    ratings: [
        {
            star: { type: Number },
            postedBy: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            comment: { type: String }
        }
    ],
    totalRatings: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

//Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

user routes
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router()
const user = require('../controllers/user.controller')
const { verifyAccessToken, isAdmin } = require('../middlewares/verifyToken')

routes.put('/cart', [verifyAccessToken], user.updateCart)
module.exports = routes

user controller
const updateCart = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { _id } = req.user;
    const { pid, quantity, color } = req.body;
    if (!pid|| !quantity || !color) throw new Error('Missing inputs');
    const user = await User.findById(_id).select('cart')
    const alreadyExistsCart = user?.cart?.find(el => el.product.toString() === pid);
    if (alreadyExistsCart) {

    } else {
        const response = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { $push: { cart: { product: pid, quantity, color } } }, { new: true });
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: response ? true : false,
            updatedCart: response ? response : 'Some thing went wrong'
        })
    }
})

i'm testing api in post man and i get stuck
enter image description here
I have try converting the _id which is string, to ObjectId like
mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
but nothing happen

Where have you mounted your routers? Share the code where you mount them using app.use(). It is likley that you have a route /user/:id which is picking up /user/cart and thinks the word cart is an _id based on your route handling design.
